# how to show or hide dropdown, if chekbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello guys (: can you help me how to show or hide my option if check box is not checked

this is the code

```
<label>Busy</label>:</label><br><br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
     <input type="checkbox" name="busy"  id="busy" value="busy">
     <label for="busy">Busy</label>
</div><br>
<div id="dropdownHolder">
    <label>Add Time</label>:
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="time">
                <option value = "30min">30 minute</option>
                <option value ="1hr">1 hour</option>
                <option value ="1hr30min">1 hour 30minute</option>
                <option value ="2hr">2 hour</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    //initially all dropdowns are hidden
    $('#dropdownHolder select').hide();
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var isOnCall = $('.OnCall:checked').length,
            anyOther = $('.other:checked').length;
        $('#dropdownHolder select').hide();
        if (isOnCall > 0 &&  anyOther > 0){
            $('#time').show();
        }

    })


});
</script>
```

that jquery is not mine i am just copy paste it. i can't show the option menu when even i have check the box can you help me how to solve this?

Comment: Where is `OnCall` or `other` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#dropdownHolder select').hide(); //initially dropdown is hidden
$('#busy').change(function() { //change click to hidden

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //check if checkbox is checked
    $('#dropdownHolder select').show(); //show if checked
  } else {
    $('#dropdownHolder select').hide(); //hide if unchecked
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Busy</label>:</label>
<br>
<br>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
  <input type="checkbox" name="busy" id="busy" value="busy">
  <label for="busy">Busy</label>
</div>
<br>
<div id="dropdownHolder">
  <label>Add Time</label>:
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select id="time">
        <option value="30min">30 minute</option>
        <option value="1hr">1 hour</option>
        <option value="1hr30min">1 hour 30minute</option>
        <option value="2hr">2 hour</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Change the event click to change event. When using checkbox it is better to use change event.
2. `if (isOnCall > 0 &&  anyOther > 0){` This condition is not needed maybe a mistake from copy paste.
3. TO check if the checkbox is checked you can use `$(':checkbox').is(':checked')` condition

Comment: @KelvinHalim did you copy paste my code like what you did with your previous code?if you did it will work.try the demo so you can see for yourself

Comment: yes i am copy paste your code, yes i demo it and its work, but i dont know what happen when i use ur code, it doesnt work, eventhough i paste the scipt in new document still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

This Might work for you. I am in hurry right now, hence not looked into deeply. Please modify something in the code for proper work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//$('#dropdownHolder select').hide();
$('#busy').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //check if checkbox is checked
        open($('#dropdownHolder select'));
    } else {
        $('#dropdownHolder select').trigger("click");; //hide if unchecked
    }

});

function open(elem) {
if (document.createEvent) {
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
} else if (element.fireEvent) {
    elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
}
}

});
```

Comment: @kelvin I have tested this in chrome, its working fine. Not sure about other browsers.